# Getting multiple values in multiple rows from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using WordPress. I want to get everything from the `wp_posts` table and two values from the `postmeta` table.

The "wp_postmeta" has the columns "post_id", "meta_key", and "meta_value".

So far, I'm able to get one of the "meta_value":

```
SELECT wp_post.*, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS votes 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE post_type='post' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'votes'
```

However, I also want to get another "meta_value" with the same "post_id" but a different "meta_key". How can I extend this query to the "meta_value"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding your additional meta_key to the query with the `IN` clause. Let's say it's the string value `foo` that you want to add:

```
SELECT wp_post.*, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS votes 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE post_type='post' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('votes', 'foo');
```

Comment: The closet I got was the following, but it still doesn't work. Both "votes" and "thumb" have the same value in the MySQL output: `SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.meta_value AS votes, wp_postmeta.meta_value AS thumb
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE post_type =  'post'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key
IN (
'votes',  'thumb'
)`

Comment: What do you mean 'same value'? Are you saying it's not valid? Where id dyou ever mention that they need to have different 'values'? Suggest editing your question with sample input and output values.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want multiple rows per post, you can do this by having multiple joins:

```
SELECT wp_post.*, metavotes.meta_value AS votes, metaother.meta_value AS other
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta metavotes 
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'votes') 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta metaother
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'other') 
WHERE post_type='post'
```

(this assumes there is always exactly 1 row for each piece of metadata in wp_postmeta. I'm not familiar enough with wordpress to know whether this is the case. If metadata is optional, use LEFT OUTER JOIN's instead. If you can have multiple, what kind of output do you want?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.meta_value, wp_postmeta.meta_key
       FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON(wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
       WHERE wp_posts.post_type='post'
             AND wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('votes', ...)
```